# req.files returning Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: node.js, express, request, multer

i am using multer storage and its working fine but the error here when the input fields is empty it keeps sending **"File has been uploaded"** , what i want to make when the request files is undefined or null it returns "Fields is empty" other than that it checks if its an image or pdf file

```
const uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {

try {
    
    await upload(req, res);
    console.log(req.files);
  
    if (req.files == undefined) {
        return res.send({message : "Fields is Empty"})
    }
    if (req.files !== undefined) {
        if (req.files.bookCover[0].fieldname == "bookCover" && req.files.bookCover[0].bucketName != 'photos' ) {
            return res.send({ message: "Please Upload an Image" })
        }
        if (req.files.bookFile[0].fieldname == "bookFile" && req.files.bookFile[0].bucketName != 'pdf') {
            return res.send({ message: "Please Upload a PDF File" })
        }
    }
    res.send({ message : "File has been uploaded. "})
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.send({ message : "Error Uploading the File !"})
}
```

}

it keeps giving me this error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')** so i wrapped them inside another if statement if fields is not undefined it checks if its an image or pdf file uploaded

but its not working

Comment: Think about this: What if `req.files.bookCover` is not existing? So, `req.files` is an object and not undefined, but it has no property `bookCover`. Then, `req.files.bookCover` will be `undefined` and therefore `req.files.bookCover[0]` becomes now `undefined[0]` and will cause the error you see... (Same for `bookFile` of course.) Easiest solution: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: @CherryDT yea i see your point but its the only way to check if its a file i need to be uploaded or not so i wrapped it to another if statement but it keeps returning the error , i keep thinking what causing the problem but i cannot get it resolved

Comment: I already linked the solution to you in my comment.

Comment: @CherryDT thank you so much will check it out and tell you if it works

Comment: What I meant: `req.files.bookCover?.[0].fieldname` for example (notice the `?.`) - if it's also possible that `bookCover` exists but is an empty array then you need `req.files.bookCover?.[0]?.fieldname` instead.

Comment: @CherryDT thank you the error is gone now i have to check if the fields input files has files or not , will try to figure it out , thank you for help i didn't know about that optional operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix i made thank to @CherryDT

```
try{
    await upload(req, res);
    console.log(req.files);
    if (!req.files.bookCover ) {
        return res.send({ message: "Book Cover is Empty" });
    } else if (!req.files.bookFile) {
        return res.send({ message: "Book File is Empty" });
    }
    else {
    if (req.files.bookCover?.[0].fieldname == "bookCover" && req.files.bookCover?.[0].bucketName != 'photos' ) {
        return res.send({ message: "Please Upload an Image" })
    }
    if (req.files.bookFile?.[0].fieldname == "bookFile" && req.files.bookFile?.[0].bucketName != 'pdf' ) {
        return res.send({ message: "Please Upload a PDF File" })
        }
    }
    res.send({ message: "File has been uploaded. " })
}
 catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.send({ message : "Error Uploading the File !"})
}
```